Construct a sequence of increasing a.e random variable $X_n$ that converge to $X$ but not in expectation
I am doing an exercise on probability theory where I am tasked with constructing a sequence of increasing a.e random variable $X_n$ that converge to $X$ but, $\mathbb{E}[X_n] \neq \mathbb{E}[X]$. The ambient sample space is the set of positive integers, $\Omega = \mathbb{Z}_+$ with the $\sigma$-field it's powerset, $2^\Omega$. I am having a lot of trouble coming up with such an example, especially when I don't even know the what probability measure to use. Any hint or insights is appreciated.
Cheers

$X_n(\omega)=-2^{\omega}$ if $\omega \ge n $ and $0$ if $\omega <n$, $X=0$. [$P({n})=2^{-n}$].

@geetha290krm. Thanks for the help, but perhaps I am more curious behind the motivation of the definition of $X_n$. What the "trick" or concept here ? I know from MCT it needs to be negative, but thats pretty much where I got stucked.

A well known and trivial example on $\mathbb R$ with Lebesgue measure is $X_n=-1_{(n,\infty)}, X=0$. I have just modified it to your situation.
